# A quadratic-function problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

At what values of 'a' does the function $f\left(x\right)=-x^2+\left(a-1\right)x+2$ increases on the interval (1,2)?

I've tried taking $f'(x)\ge 0$ but donot how to proceed, need help.

Thank You.

Comment: What is $D$? ${}{}{}$

Comment: Is that "increases somewhere" or "increases everywhere" on the given interval?

Comment: "D" is discriminant here, $D=b^2-4ac$

Answer (score 2):

Try to draw out the function. It is a parabola with axis of symmetry $x=(a-1)/2$, and it is increasing on the left side of the axis, while decreasing on the right side of the axis. Since you want to find such  a so that $f(x)$ increases on $(1,2)$, the end point $x=2$ has to be on the left of the axis. 
Or, by taking the derivative of $f(x)$ as you did, you'll get $f'(x)=-2x+(a-1)$, which is a decreasing linear function. So as long as $f'(x)>0$ at the point of $x=2$, you can be ensured that the function is strictly increasing on the interval (1,2).